# Resharper Braces auto-format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, resharper, curly-braces, braces

I have a problem with Resharper and auto formating braces.
Since a while Resharper don't add closing braces while I am typing an opening brace.
Also when I am typing a closing brace at the last line of a method, the closing brace of the method will be removed.

Example:

```
private void Method()
{
    if(true)
    { // If I type '{' resharper of vs2010 will normally add a '}' 
      // but I don't know why not now
}
private void AnotherMethod(){}
```

If am am manually add the closing brace the closing brace of the method is removed and `AnotherMethod()` is indented.

```
private void Method()
{
    if(true)
    {
    } // Why is the closing brace of the method removed?
    private void AnotherMethod(){}
```

My related settings of resharper:
***Formatting style > Braces Layout***:
 - ***Braces Layout***: for all *At next line (BSD style)* (and *Empty braces formatting: On different lines*)
 - ***Force Braces***: for all *Add braces*

***IntelliSence > Completion Behavior***:
 - *Enabled: **Automatically insert parentheses after completion***
 +- *selected: **Both opening and closing***

***Editor***
 - *Enabled: **Auto-insert closing brace***
 +-*selected: **On typing an opening brace***

**What are the required resharper settings to solve this problem?**

Comment: May be option Environment>Editor > _Auto-insert closing brace_ will be interesting to you

Comment: @alpha-mouse thanks for replay. _Auto-insert closing brace_ is enabled and _On typing an opening brace_ is selected.

Comment: What version of re-sharper are you using? It works fine for me on 5.1.3000.12 (which is newer than your post date)

Comment: @ChrisFletcher: Thanks for responding: I am using 5.1.3000.12 also on Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1.

Comment: Some other extensions may be preventing ReSharper, if you use any.